# How to fix " code should explicitly check to see if permission is available " error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have simple fragment that aim to fetch user current location.

The error I got is clear, we need to check if the user grant us location permissions:

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should
> explicitly check to see if permission is available (with
> checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException

But I already made permission check, basically the fetch couldn't be done without user granting us permission, so why do I need to check twice?

My flow is like this:

```
 if (activityListener.checkPermissions()) {
    showMapAndFetchLocation()
}
```

Inside `showMapAndFetchLocation` method

```
initLocationProvider()
val mapFragment =
    childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
mapFragment?.getMapAsync(callback)
```

And last, inside `initLocationProvider` method

```
if (isLocationEnabled()) {
    fusedLocationClient   //**Error**
        .lastLocation    //**Error**
        .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<Location> ->
            val location = task.result
            location?.let {
                Log.d(TAG, "getUserLastLocation: LAT ${it.latitude}")
                Log.d(TAG, "getUserLastLocation: LNG ${it.longitude}")
            }
           ?: requestNewLocationData()
        }
}
```

As you can see, I'm checking frist  `if (activityListener.checkPermissions())` and only then fire the fetching process.

Do I really need to check twice or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just add a `try/catch(SecurityException)` block, that lint check doesn't realize if you call `checkPermission` inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pawel Suggested, I needed to add try/catch block and catch SecurityException exception.

Now the method looks like this:

```
try {

        fusedLocationClient
            .lastLocation
            .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<Location> ->
                val location = task.result
                location?.let {
                    Log.d(TAG, "getUserLastLocation: LAT ${it.latitude}")
                    Log.d(TAG, "getUserLastLocation: LNG ${it.longitude}")
                    setLngLat(it.latitude, it.longitude)
                    initMap()

                }
                    ?: requestNewLocationData()
            }
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
        activityListener.isLocationPermissionGranted()
    }
```